# How do I set Facebook to show only a profile owner's posts in his/her wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

How do I set Facebook to show only a profile owner's posts in his/her wall? Is there a Facebook feature or a browser extension (Opera/Firefox/Chrome) that could do this?

(Strange: I remember being able to do this around a month ago as a Facebook feature or thru the [Better Facebook](http://betterfacebook.net/) Opera/Firefox/Chrome extension, but can't seem to find where to toggle that feature now.)

Comment: You can do that for Pages but Facebook removed that option for personal profiles when they switched to the new profile layout.

Comment: @mark4o: If your comment is the final answer to this question you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I was just commenting that Facebook does not support this natively.  The question asks about a browser extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension you mentioned.

- Go to the options
- Select Filtering
- Select your name
- Add all types you want to apply
- And select "Move to Tab"

Save your settings and refresh. You should get the following.

[image: Filtered Tabbing]